# react native : reduce size of picker - what is the way to do it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, datepicker

in my example so the picker display the numbers but the aize of it is to long and its display in all over the screen .

i want to reduce its size, how i do it ?

in this code i just build drop list picker that have numbers 1-31 and i try to reduce the size of this picker but could not do it .
now its Throws out the app when I want to select a number

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import { Picker } from '@react-native-community/picker';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import * as wpActions from '../redux/actions';

const Settings = () => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('1');
  const [selectedValue2, setSelectedValue2] = useState('month);
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(selectedValue, selectedValue2);
    const data = { selectedValue, selectedValue2 };
    dispatch(wpActions.dateTime(data));
  };

  const pickerArray = [...Array(10)];

  return (
    <>
      <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>choose number</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Picker
          mode="dropdown"
          //pickerStyleType={}
          selectedValue={selectedValue}
          style={{
            height: 50,
            width: 150,
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
          }}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
        >
          {pickerArray.map((_, i) => (
            <Picker.Item label={i} value={i} />
          ))}

          <Picker.Item label="1" value="1" />
          <Picker.Item label="2" value="2" />
          <Picker.Item label="3" value="3" />
          <Picker.Item label="4" value="4" />
          <Picker.Item label="5" value="5" />
          <Picker.Item label="6" value="6" />
          <Picker.Item label="7" value="7" />
          <Picker.Item label="8" value="8" />
          <Picker.Item label="9" value="9" />
          <Picker.Item label="10" value="10" />
          <Picker.Item label="11" value="11" />
          <Picker.Item label="12" value="12" />
          <Picker.Item label="13" value="13" />
          <Picker.Item label="14" value="14" />
          <Picker.Item label="15" value="15" />
          <Picker.Item label="16" value="16" />
          <Picker.Item label="17" value="17" />
          <Picker.Item label="18" value="18" />
          <Picker.Item label="19" value="19" />
          <Picker.Item label="20" value="20" />
          <Picker.Item label="21" value="21" />
          <Picker.Item label="22" value="22" />
          <Picker.Item label="23" value="23" />
          <Picker.Item label="24" value="24" />
          <Picker.Item label="25" value="25" />
          <Picker.Item label="26" value="26" />
          <Picker.Item label="27" value="27" />
          <Picker.Item label="28" value="28" />
          <Picker.Item label="29" value="29" />
          <Picker.Item label="30" value="30" />
          <Picker.Item label="31" value="31" />
        </Picker>

        <Picker
          mode="dropdown"
          selectedValue={selectedValue2}
          style={{
            height: 50,
            width: 150,
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
          }}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue2(itemValue)}
        >
          <Picker.Item label="day" value="day" />
          <Picker.Item label="week" value="week" />
          <Picker.Item label="month" value="month" />
          <Picker.Item label="year" value="year" />
        </Picker>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Button title="Submit" onPress={() => handleSubmit()} />
      </View>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
    marginRight: 100,
    marginTop: 40,
  },
  text: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 20,
    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
  },
});

export default Settings;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a map function to reduce your picker item length

```
<Picker>
  {[...Array(31)].map((_, i) => (
    <Picker.Item label={i} value={i} />
  ))}
</Picker>
```

modified code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, StyleSheet, Picker, View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

  const pickerArray = [...Array(10)];

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text> Picker Value: {value}</Text>
      <Picker
        mode="dropdown"
        //pickerStyleType={}
        selectedValue={value}
        style={styles.picker}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setValue(itemValue)}>
        {pickerArray.map((_, i) => (
          <Picker.Item label={i} value={i} />
        ))}
      </Picker>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' },
  picker: {
    height: 50,
    width: 150,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  },
});
```

[Snack Example](https://snack.expo.io/@chawki726/hiding-tab-bar-in-specific-screens-%7C-react-navigation?platform=android&name=Hiding%20tab%20bar%20in%20specific%20screens%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40%5E0.1.7%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.8.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.9.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.7.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.9.0%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.0.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40%5E1.7.0%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40%5E3.0.2%2Creact-native-screens%40%5E2.9.0%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.15.1&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fstatus-bar.js)

Comment: can u show me your example in my code ?  coz i didnt understand

Comment: i have  problem there .. i edit my all code above . now its Throws out the app when I want to select a number

Comment: what error you get, when you trying to select a number?

Comment: no error.. its just close the app. 
can u check my code that i edit above with ur idea ?

Comment: I have added a snack example above, refer that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220833/discussion-between-c-k-and-shira).